# Excel DateValue = Formatting

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

Looking to convert the following `2015-10-07T23:59:59` into something that Excel actually recognizes as a date so I can then graph/chart with this data... I tried using datevalue and custom formatting but can't get the syntax quite right.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get datetime from your string, you only need to replace `T` with space, convert to numeric and apply appropriate cell format.:

```
=1*SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T"," ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if Excel can understand that type of format date, you should try to write your own custom function to get it in the format that you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss for the custom format?

Answer (score 0):

If the timestamp isn't needed, use `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))`. If it is needed, then use `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))`. (Where cell A1 contains the datetime string you are trying to parse).

This will return the Julian date value (E.g. 42284 for the day, 42284.96 for day & time) which you can then apply Excel's built in date formatting to, it will also work for charts and pivot table grouping.